# Que variables necesito para el algoritmo

Tags: pseudocódigo, diagrama-de-flujo

La calificación de programación se calificara de la siguiente forma: 20% de tareas, 30% de prácticas, 40% exámenes y 10% de asistencia.
Se consideran 20 asistencias para obtener la calificación más alta y de ahi depende cuantas asistencias haya tenido para obtener su calificación.
Ya tengo mi variable TA=Total asistencias, A=Asistencias

TA=A*100/20
Qué más necesito?
Gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack overflow. Te invito a revisar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y la sección de [preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que puedas mejorar tus preguntas en las próximas ocasiones. Por favor indica mediante tags sobre qué tecnología estás trabajando y agrega código que hayas realizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta la cual **no es de programacion pero si forma parte del grupo de Pseudocodigo es bien valida y te doy la bienvenida**.

He analizado el problema y para la resolucion necesitas emplear 9 variables para el calculo de la calificacion:

Lo explico de la siguiente forma:

La nota general de programacion esta dividia en 4 grupos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dicen que cada grupo tiene un porcentaje de la nota total y tambien te dicen que la asistencia es tomada como optima en 20 evaluaciones.

Entonces exlicando cada variable:

**PASO 1**

1) Necesita una variable que totalice las notas de las tareas y esta se promedie con la cantidad de tareas colocadas para la clase o (Ne) que seria numero de evaluaciones, el cual debes colocar un numero para cada uno de su grupo.

```
TareaNs=(Nota1+Nota2+Nota..)/Ne
```

2) Tambien necesitas una variable para totalizar el numero de practicas y promediarlas.

```
PracticaNs=(Nota1+Nota2+Nota..)/Ne
```

3) Necesitas otra variable para totalizar el numero de examenes y promediar su cantidad.

```
ExamentesNs=(Nota1+Nota2+Nota..)/Ne
```

4) Tambien vas a necesitar una variable para sumar cada asistencia.

```
AsistenciaNs=(Eval1 + Eval2 … Eval20)
```

Ya teniendo esa parte lista ahora puedes sacar su nota ponderada la cual correspondera con la cuota que se considera para cada evaluacion.

**PASO 2**

5) Calcula la nota ponderada para la tarea con esta formula:

```
TareaNp=TareaNs * Porcentaje / 100
```

6) Calcula la nota pondera para la practica

```
PracticaNp=PracticaNs * Porcentaje / 100
```

7) Calcula la nota ponderada para los examenes

```
ExamenesNp=ExamenesNs * Porcentaje / 100
```

8)  Calcula la nota pondera para la asistencia.

```
AsistenciaNp=AsistenciaNs * Porcentaje / 100
```

**PASO 3**

Teniendo toda las notas ponderadas ya puedes totalizar para
tener la nota final.

9) La nota final sera la suma de todas las notas ponderadas.

```
TotalNotas = TareaNp + PracticaNp + ExamenesNp + AsistenciaNp
```

Aqui abajo esta una tabla de ejemplo aplicando cada una de las variables antes mencionadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta tabla se puede explicar mejor el uso de las variables en la formula, el numero de evaluaciones (Ne),Las notas Sacadas (Ns), las notas ponderadas (Np) y Total de Notas.